# how to read a customer provided log file?

Tags: java

so I have a log file like this

```
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
<someTag>someDetail</someTag>
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
<someTag>someDetail</someTag>
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

here is my code to read the file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DummyReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Hussi/logFile.log"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                if(sCurrentLine.contains("<"))
                {
                    System.out.println("==>>>"+sCurrentLine);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but in my output I am getting

```
b l a h b l a h b l a h 
< s o m e T a g >s o m e D e t a i l < / s o m e T a g >
b l a h b l a h b l a h 
< s o m e T a g >s o m e D e t a i l < / s o m e T a g >
b l a h b l a h b l a h 
< s o m e T a g >s o m e D e t a i l < / s o m e T a g >
```

the space between the characters is actually some squares

what can I do to read the file correctly

Do I have to mention , file format , anything like that ??

[image: this is the console]

Comment: sCurrentLine.replaceAll(" ", "");

Comment: What about using an XML parser to get at your tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your file is in UTF-16 text encoding format

I have changed two lines and now the programs works okay.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/temp/test3.txt");
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-16LE"));
```

**Modified working program**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DummyReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/temp/test3.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-16LE"));
            //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/temp/test3.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                /*if(sCurrentLine.contains("<"))
                {
                    System.out.println("==>>>"+sCurrentLine);
                }*/
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```